# std::vector out of range

Tags: c++, opengl, vector, standard-library

Currently I am trying to render a .obj model that I loaded into vectors. I am trying to pull the Vector3D object out of the array but it gives me an out of range error. It only goes to five before the array crashes, when the array has 12 objects for example. Here is the code for the rendering.

```
glBegin(GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP);

for (int indx = 0; indx < mv3_faces.size(); ++indx)
{
    if (mb_print_once)
    {
        std::cout << "Rendering Loop....Faces at 8: " << mv3_faces.at(5).x << " Current Index: " << indx << std::endl;
        std::cout << "Rendering Loop X: " << mv3_faces.at(indx).x << " Y: " << mv3_faces.at(indx).y << " Z: " << mv3_faces.at(indx).z << std::endl;
    }

    glColor4f(1.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f);

    glVertex3f(mv3_vertices.at(mv3_faces.at(indx).x).x, mv3_vertices.at(mv3_faces.at(indx).y).y, mv3_vertices.at(mv3_faces.at(indx).z).z);
}

mb_print_once = false;
glEnd();
```

Ignore the mb_print_once... that is for debugging purposes.

Comment: Which line does the error correspond to?  And are you sure that there are 12 elements in the vector?  Could you add `std::cout << mv3_faces.size() << std::endl;` before the loop, to confirm?

Comment: Also, note that it's considered good etiquette to *remove* all irrelevant details from your code snippet...

Comment: Which vector is getting the out-of-range error - faces, or vertices?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Did you remember that vertex indices in .OBJ files start at 1 rather than 0? So you have to decrement the vertex indices by 1 after reading them from an "f" tag.

And also as a little comment, I would strongly suggest using `[]` instead of `.at`, although in this example it was a good idea, so you got the exception. But in general the range-checking overhead is not worth it, especially in such a highly to optimize loop.

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that the exception comes from the `mv3_vertices.at` call: `indx` should be in range for `mv3_faces`, because of how that loop is made, so probably it's what is stored inside it that it's not a valid index for `mv3_vertices`.

If I were you I would step in with a debugger to find exactly whence the exception comes from (or you can split the `glVertex3f(...)` line in multiple statements and add some logging), and trace whence the bad data comes from.

Answer (score 0):

```
glVertex3f(mv3_vertices.at(mv3_faces.at(indx).x).x, mv3_vertices.at(mv3_faces.at(indx).y).y, mv3_vertices.at(mv3_faces.at(indx).z).z);
```

I suspect this line.

Have you made sure that `mv3_faces.at(indx).x < mv3_vertices.size()` ?  If that is not true, then you will get out of range exception. Check out the other two  also; that is, `mv3_faces.at(indx).y`, and `mv3_faces.at(indx).z`.

Whenever you use [`std::vector::at()`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/stl/vector/at/) function, make sure that the index which you pass to `at()` is within range of the of the vector's size, otherwise `at()` will throw an `out_of_range` exception. If you don't make sure that, then use try-catch block to handle this exception and the rest of the program flow.